# Pulseaudio: how to restart without restart X11 if delete tmp?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have deleted (because of errors) the /tmp folder, which contains the pulseaudio folder.
The question is: how to restart pulseaudio without restarting X11?
If I restart X11, pulseaudio works fine. 
I have tried

```
start-pulseaudio-x11
```

which gives this error

```
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {54116d3eeebf4e5b5e1f50d757286535}unix:/tmp/pulse-l7iX3tHbLHHy/native, refusing to start/autospawn.
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

I have tried this

```
pulseaudio --start
```

and it gives this error

```
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {54116d3eeebf4e5b5e1f50d757286535}unix:/tmp/pulse-l7iX3tHbLHHy/native, refusing to start/autospawn.
```

How do I restart pulseaudio?

p.s. Of course I have killed the previous pulseaudio daemon.

Comment: Did you recreate `/tmp`?

Comment: sure,with 1777 permissions